# Является ли хорошей практикой в качестве первичного ключа использовать поле типа Date?

Tags: база-данных

Добрый день! Интересует вопрос, который написан в теме. Не будет ли проблем с обработкой данных. Лучше использовать такой ключ или суррогатный? Знает ли кто книги, в которых можно прочитать про хорошую практику создания базы данных?

Comment: В моем случае также учитывается время.

Comment: Лучше всего делать первичным ключем поле (или совокупность полей), которое является действительно уникальным идентификатором события в *реальном мире*, данные о котором вы храните.

Хорошая практика (и теория) -- http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/5-8459-0384-X.html

Comment: Нет, не является. В идеале первичный ключ должен быть суррогатным, то есть  вообще не  содержать данных, относящихся к состоянию хранимой сущности. Плюс к тому же, как верно заметил @maxmail, даты могут и повторяться, что аннулирует ценность подобного ключа.

Comment: @DreamChild, интересно,

    В идеале первичный ключ должен быть суррогатным, то есть вообще не содержать данных, относящихся к состоянию хранимой сущности

это чье мнение?

Comment: @avp, если просите указать каких-нибудь авторитетных личностей типа Кнута или хотя бы Спольски, то не назову (хотя, наверное, можно при желании найти слова таких личностей в подтверждение сказанному). Это утверждение основано на мнениях различных людей и собственном. Я, конечно, не претендую на то, чтобы быть истиной в последней инстанции, однако польза от подобного подхода, по-моему, очевидна.

Comment: @DreamChild, Вы, наверное, имели в виду Кодда, а не Кнута?

Я, конечно, давно не занимался базами, но не думал, что проблема уже настолько запущена.

Кстати, быстренький просмотр в гугле вывел [на нечто похожее](http://habrahabr.ru/post/107834/).

Comment: @avp, нет, я имел в виду именно Кнута как, вероятно, самого авторитетного (или хотя бы одного из) специалиста в области компьютерных наук. Хотя, пожалуй, стоило иметь в виду действительно Кодда, поскольку он ближе к данной тематике.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать первичный ключ для поля с датой, но, как правило, так никто не делает, лучше сделать его уникальным идентификатором, для того чтоб наверняка избежать проблем.  
В вашем случае разве не может быть 2 записи с одной датой?

Comment: Даже если вы учитываете время - это не повод делать его первичным ключом, так как запрос на добавление может прийти одновременно - секунда в секунду. И при попытке добавить вторую запись с таким же временем будет безуспешной.
Рекомендую ознакомиться с основными понятиями создания бд на примерах
если в среде MS SQL server то можно тут :

http://bankknigs.com/jurnaly_komputernie/229964-microsoft-sql-server-2008-rukovodstvo-dlya-nachinayuschih.html